# Small build-in ssd in notebook can install linux?

Tags: linux, ssd

I bought a samsung laptop series 5. There are a 24gb ssd and normal hard disk. I need to install linux ubuntu on this notebook. Can I just install the ubuntu on the build-in 24gb ssd? If not, how can I use the 24gb ssd for anything?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install Linux on this SSD 24Gb. Modern Unix-like Operating system requires about 5Gb of disk drive.

For example, here is a requirement for Ubuntu and other Linux OSes, they all basically take about the same space.

- **[Ubuntu Desktop Edition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)**

> ```
> 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
> 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
> 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
> VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
> Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
>
> Internet access is helpful
> ```

- **[Debian](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/ch03s04.html.en)**
  [image]
- **[Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/en_GB/get-fedora)**

> - 1 GB RAM
> - 10 GB disk space
> - 64-bit only

- **[OpenSUSE](http://en.opensuse.org/Hardware_requirements)**

> ```
> Pentium* III 500 MHz or higher processor (Pentium 4 2.4 GHz or higher or any AMD64 or Intel64 processor recommended)
> Main memory: 1 GB physical RAM (2 GB recommended)
> Hard disk: 3 GB available disk space for a minimal install, 5 GB available for a graphical desktop (more recommended)
> Sound and graphics cards: supports most modern sound and graphics cards, 800 x 600 display resolution (1024 x 768 or higher recommended)
> Booting from CD/DVD drive or USB-Stick for installation, or support for booting over network (you need to setup PXE by yourself,
> ```
>
> look also at PXE boot installation) or an existing installation of
>   openSUSE, more information at Installation without CD

Comment: I've corrected your Fedora link, which was to the requirements *for running virutalization*, meaning, a system which hosts other virtual systems.  The correct link for the requirements of the Fedora 20 desktop edition is **[here](http://fedoraproject.org/en_GB/get-fedora)** and they are: 10 GB hard drive space, 1 GB RAM, 64-bit processor.

Answer (score 2):

If low resource consumption matters for you, you could decide to install [LUbuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) which is explicitly designed for being lightweight. That's why I like it.